# 'Search' endpoint seems unstable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When using Forge Data Management API endpoint
*projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search* we have two problems.

1. It seems that we sometimes have to wait for several minutes (hours?)
   after a model is uploaded until it can be found by the search.
2. We often get error 429 "Too Many Requests" even that we only call do
   very few calls (less than  10 within an hour).

These issues makes the endpoint hard to use in production code. Is there anything we can do to improve the success rate? Is Autodesk going to improve the endpoint?

This question is related to [How to find cloud Item id of a Revit model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222375/how-to-find-cloud-item-id-of-a-revit-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are aware of those issues and working on improving things in those areas. However, I cannot tell when exactly those will become available.

In the meantime, depending on your workflow, there are two things that could be of help:

1. Use [webhooks](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/) in order to be notified about new files being added to BIM 360/ACC
2. Use [folder/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) endpoint to find the file you need, which also supports filtering just like the [folder/search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/) endpoint. You would have to iterate through subfolders though if you wanted to look for items in them as well. Newly added files should show up here straight away.